# How do you display an image stored in a database on a php page?

Tags: php, mysql, image, blob

I've uploaded an image into a table in my database, and I'd like to display the image on a page using php. So far all it does is display a large slab of ugly code, I was just wondering how I can change this to echo the actual image?

Answer (score 1):

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAHIAAAA6CAYAAABs1g18AAAAGXRFWHRTb2Z0d2FyZQBBZG9iZSBJbWFnZVJlYWR5ccllPAAABRhJREFUeNrsXY+VsjAMR98twAo6Ao4gI+gIOIKOgCPICDoCjCAjXFdgha+5C3dcv/QfFB5i8h5PD21Bfk3yS9L2VpGnlGW5kS9wJMTHNRxpmjYRy6SycgRvL18OeMQOTYQ8HvIoJKiiz43hgHkq1zvK/h6e/TyJQXeV/VyWBOSHA4C5RvtMAiCc4ZB9FPjgRI8+YuKcrySO515a1hoAY3nc4G2AH52BZsn+MjaAEwIJICKAIR889HljMCcyrR0QE4v/q/BVBQva7Q1tAczG18+x+PvIswHEAslLbfGrMZKiXEOMAMy6LwlisQCJLPFMfKdBtli5dIihRyH7A627Iaiq5sJ1ThP9xoIgSdWSNVIHYmrTQgOgRyRNqm/M5PnrFFopr3F6B41cd8whRUSufUBU5EL4U93AYRnIWimCIiSI1wAaAZpJ9bPnxx8eyI3Gt4QybwWa6T/BvbQECUMQFkhd3jSkPFgrxwcynuBaNT/u6eJIlbGOBWSNIUDFEIwPZFAtBfYrfeIOSRSXuUYCsprCXwUIZWYnmEhJFMIocMDWjn206c2EsGLCJd42aWSyBNMnHxLEq7niMrY2qyDbQUbqrrTbwUPtxN1ZZCitQV4ZSd6DyoxhmRD6OFjuRUS/KdLGRHYowJZaqYgjt9Lchmi3QYA/cXBsHK6VfWNR5jgA1DLhwfFe4HqfODBpINEECCLO47LT/+HSvSd/OCOgQ8qE0DbHQUBqpC4BkKMPYPkFY4iAJXhGAYr1qmaqQDbECCg5A2NMchzR567aA4xcRKclI405Bmt46vYD7/Gcjqfk6GP/kh1wovIDSHDfiAs/8bOCQ4cf4qMt7eH5Cucr3S0aWGFfjdLHD8EhCFvXQlSqRrY5UV2O9cfZtk77jUFMXeqzCEZqSK4ICkSin2tE12/3rbVcE41OBjBjBPSdJ1N5lfYQpIuhr8axnyIy5KvXmkYnw8VbcwtTNj7fDNCmT2kPQXA+bxpEXkB21HlnSQq0gD67jnfh5KavVJa/XQYEFSaagWwbgjNA+ywstLpEWTKgc5gwVpsyO1bTII+tA6B7BPS+0PiznuM9gPKsPVXbFdADMtwbJxSmkXWfRh6AZhyyzBjIHoDmnCGaMZAKjd5hyNJYCBGDOVcg28AXQ5atAVDO3c4dSALQnYblfa3M4kc/cyA7gMIUBQCTyl4kugIpy8yA7ACqK8Uwk30lIFGOEV3rPDAELwQkr/9YjkaCPDQhCcsrAYlF1v8W8jAEYeQDY7qn6tNGWudfq+YUEr6uq6FZzBpJMUfWFDatLHMCciw2mRC+k81qCCA1DzK4aUVfrJpxnloZWCPVnOgYy8L3GvKjE96HpweQoy7iwVQclVutLOEKJxA8gaRCjSzgNI2zhh3bQhzBCQQPIHGaHaUd96GJbZz3Smmjy16u6j3FuKyNxcBarxqWWfYFE0tVVO1Rl3t1Mb05V00MQCJ71YHpNaMcsjWAfkQvPPkaNC7LqTG7JAhGXTKYf+VDeXAX9IvURoAwtTFHvyYIxtnd5tPkywrPafcwbeSuGVwFau3b76NO7SHQrvqhfFE8kM0Wvpv8gVYiYBlxL+fW/34bgP6bIC7JR7YPDubcHCPzIp4+cum7U6NlhZgK7lua3KGLeFwE2m+HblDYWSHG2SAfINuwBBfxbJEIuWZbBH4fAExD7cvaGVyXyH0dhiAYc92z3ZDfUVv+jgb8HrHy7WVO/8BFcy9vuTz+nwADAGnOR39Yg/QkAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC" alt="Slim"/>
```

ie :

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,your databse string from database" alt="Slim"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try out below code, some part taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2633908/php-display-image-with-header)

```
$filename = basename($file);
$file_extension = strtolower(substr(strrchr($filename,"."),1));

switch( $file_extension ) {
    case "gif": $ctype="image/gif"; break;
    case "png": $ctype="image/png"; break;
    case "jpeg":
    case "jpg": $ctype="image/jpg"; break;
    default:
}
header('Content-type:'.$ctype);
readfile($file);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = mysql_query('select image from table');

$row = mysql_fetch_assco($query);

$image = $row['image'];

echo "<img src='type:image/png;path/yourpath/'$image>";
```