# Loading Image increment counter in database

Tags: php, mysql

I have found on a website that I can create an image that I can send in an email .. When the email is opened, a notification is sent back to me .. I want to know how I can achieve this in respect to PHP and MySQL .. I have a table that holds IDs and counter values for these IDs .. I want, when an image is called, the appropriate ID Counter is increamented by 1.

Comment: It is possible that the method that website uses is patented and using the same method might cause a lawsuit.

Comment: @andho then it would a massive class action lawsuit as a million and one sites use the same technique =oP

Answer (score 2):

You place an image tag inside your email body like below:

```
<img src='http://www.abc.com/track.php?id=XX&a=22' width='1' height='1' />
```

This track.php should render blanker image, and you can have logic to track the opened email inside your track.php. i.e. you can insert entry into DB based on GET parameters.

Comment: so, the track.php file will only contain one single line <img src='img.jpg'/> ??

Comment: @sikas No, track.php should have 1)code to track the values e.g. from GET parameters to insert into DB or whatever way you need to track 2) code to render image from php , see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2633908/php-display-image-with-header for more detail, you need to have <img > tag in my answer above into email body.