# Set the header( content-type: image/<ANY IMG FORMAT>)

Tags: php, http-headers, substr

The php file that handles the images I display only allows one image format, either .jpg, .png, .bmp, etc but not all. The imageName stores the file name of the image stored in the database including its format. this is my code, so far it doesn't work yet and I'm not sure if that's allowed. Can you help me fix it please?

```
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","tickets");
$ticket = 109;
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT image, imageName FROM tix WHERE tktNum=$ticket");


while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    $image = $row['image'];
    $imageName = $row['imageName'];
    $format = substr( $imageName, -3 ); //gets the last 3 chars of the file name, ex: "photo1.png" gets the ".png" part
    header('content-type: image/' . $format);
}
```

Comment: it should be substr -3 not -4

Comment: File name extensions don't always equal minor MIME types.

Comment: you want: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.finfo-file.php

Comment: yes I noticed the -4, and I changed it to -3 already

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP, display image with Header()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2633908/php-display-image-with-header)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The solution is to read in the file and decide which kind of image it is and basednd on it send out the appropriate header.

```
$filename = basename($file);
$file_extension = strtolower(substr(strrchr($filename,"."),1));

switch( $file_extension ) {
    case "gif": $ctype="image/gif"; break;
    case "png": $ctype="image/png"; break;
    case "jpeg":
    case "jpg": $ctype="image/jpeg"; break;
    case "svg": $ctype="image/svg+xml"; break;
    default:
}

header('Content-type: ' . $ctype);
```

Comment: @user3663049 its nice to hear that, kindly accept and upvote this answer so that others know it is resolved so that they can use this answer

Comment: Please provide the answer here instead of just providing a link to an answer.

Answer (score 13):

I just used this, just indicating it's an image but without specifying image type.

```
header("Content-type: image");
```

It seems to be working just fine regardless of file type. I tested with IE, Firefox, Safari and the Android browser.

Comment: Unlike `image/*`, `image` will inline images in some browsers that would otherwise provide images with Content-type `image/*` as a file download.