# Fetch image from C# Web API

Tags: c#, reactjs, image, file, blob

I am trying to download an image from a server (C# Web API). I send a FileStream as a response from the server and on the React client I read it as a blob. This works well with all file extensions except svg. I can't understand why.

Server action:

```
public async Task<ManagerResult> Get(Guid id)
{
    ManagerResult res = new ManagerResult();
    try
    {
         ImageModel image = await _mainContext.Images.FindAsync(id);
         string path = image.PhysicalPath;
         FileStream file = File.Open(path, FileMode.Open);
         res.Success = true;
         res.Data = file;
    }
    catch (Exception exc)
    {
         res.Success = false;
         res.Error = exc.Message;
    }
    return res;
}
```

I think that the whole idea of opening a stream and not closing it is bad, but I don't know how else to send a blob.

React side (fetch image):

```
const imagesGet = async (guid) => {
    const url = `${API_PREFIX}/images/get?id=${guid}`
    const response = await fetch(url, { method: 'GET', headers: authHeader() })
    //Error
    const error = responseError(response)
    if (error) {
        toast.error(error)
        return null
    }
    //Success
    const body = await response.blob()
    return body
}
```

React side (create object url):

```
useEffect(() => {
    api.images.get(guid).then((data) => {
        const url = URL.createObjectURL(data)
        setSRC(url)
    }).catch(console.log)
}, [guid, setSRC])
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think, for a svg data, you need to specify blob type. Such crude is following.

```
const blob = new Blob([data], {
    type: 'image/svg+xml; charset=utf8'
  });
```

As you know svg is determined by `content-type` field in a header.
The following method helps to determine. If it is svg set `type` as I wrote, otherwise not, or just `type: 'image'` . If there is still an issue on `type`, you can make use of [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23820082).

```
async function urlIsSvg(url) {
  const r = await fetch(url, {method: 'HEAD'});
  return r.headers.get('content-type') === 'image/svg+xml';
}
```

Comment: It helps to display svg, thanks. But i get from server blob and dont now its type. O can add manualy type, and svg will show, but other images don't

Comment: In my response 'content-type' is null, I think I made a mistake on server side.

Answer (score 0):

To correctly send files, you need to use `FileStreamResult` (for Stream) or `FileContentResult` (for byte[]). Just use the `Controller.File(you_data, mime_type)`, it will choose the right Resilt on its own.

Comment: To avoid the premature stream closure you could:
    //download the binary image data and return it</br>
    byte[] imageData = blob.DownloadContent().Value.Content.ToArray();</br>
    return File(imageData, "image/jpeg");</br>