# Php return jpg as content for <img> tag

Tags: php, image

I want to return jpg image on some url in my app (example.com/my/url/to/image).

```
function footer_image(){

    $name = "/assets/img/mail.jpg";

    header("Content-Type: image/jpg", TRUE);
    header("Content-Length: " . filesize($name));
    echo file_get_contents($name);
}
```

And I got only broken image :(
Tried also this:

```
   // open the file in a binary mode
$name = "/assets/img/mail.jpg";
$fp = fopen($name, 'rb');

// send the right headers
header("Content-Type: image/jpg");
header("Content-Length: " . filesize($name));

// dump the picture and stop the script
fpassthru($fp);
exit;
```

When i var_dump $fp I get it's content. Looks like I have bad headers set.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Output an Image in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1851849/output-an-image-in-php)

Comment: What do you mean by "broken image"? Also try to set the header to `image/jpeg`

Comment: @FuzzyTree Tried solution from your link and nothing, still no output

Comment: @KhorneHoly There is icon of img, the same icon when src is invalid

Comment: What is the php version that you are using?

Comment: Suggestion: create a hyperlink to the image, right click on it and save the image to disk. Open the image in a hex editor (hexedit.com) and check that the file has a valid JPEG header.

Comment: PHP 5.2, kohana 2 it's a very old project but I have to fix some issuses in it.

Comment: @RichardBrock No matter what image I use, always the same problem

Answer (score 0):

Use Content/type: image/jpeg instead of image/jpg

For automation header Content type set you can use this:

```
$file_extension = strtolower(substr(strrchr($filename,"."),1));

switch( $file_extension ) {
    case "gif": $ctype="image/gif"; break;
    case "png": $ctype="image/png"; break;
    case "jpeg":
    case "jpg": $ctype="image/jpeg"; break;
    default:
}

header('Content-type: ' . $ctype);
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2634072/4015178

Comment: @Blejwi Are you set a header in the document start?

Comment: Just before echo content:`$img = file_get_contents($name);
        header('Content-Type: image/jpeg', TRUE);
        echo $img;`

Comment: File does not have additionals headers from includes? It's plain PHP?

Comment: It's old project built on kohana 2

Comment: You can check if headers are set: 
var_dump(headers_sent());

Comment: Got false. (Had to comment jpeg header because I couldnt see it)

Answer (score 0):

If the image is really the type JPG. Should work with: `Content-type: image/jpeg` and NOT with `Content-type: image/jpg`

To automatically check the Content-type, you could use the code below:

```
function footer_image() {
    $name = "/assets/img/mail.jpg";
    $finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE); 
    $mime = finfo_file($finfo, $name) ; // return the mimetype 
    header("Content-Type: " . $mime, TRUE);
    header("Content-Length: " . filesize($name));
    echo file_get_contents($name);
}
```

You could try this in PHP 5.2 or 5.3:

```
function footer_image() {
    $name = "/assets/img/mail.jpg";
    $mime = mime_content_type($name) ; // php 5.2 and 5.3 = return the mimetype 
    header("Content-Type: " . $mime); // remove the ', true'
    // header("Content-Length: " . filesize($name)); // remove this line to test
    echo file_get_contents($name);
}
```