# GD commands display raw image text instead of an image

Tags: php, gd

Hey i was trying to learn the GD library and i can't get my code to work, it displays raw image text instead of the actual PNG i want to display. I have Png Support enabled in the GD section by the way.

Code is very simple:

`<?php
$picture = imagecreatefrompng("test.png");
imagepng($picture);
?>`

but the result comes down to something like this:

�PNG  IHDR���.�b    pHYs���+ IDATx� etc.

Comment: Hey @Luka, welcome to StackOverflow!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Output an Image in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1851849/output-an-image-in-php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to tell the Browser, that it is image data.

Add

```
header("Content-type:image/png");
```

So it should be:

```
<?php
    header("Content-type:image/png");
    $picture = imagecreatefrompng("test.png");
    imagepng($picture);
?>
```

For more information and other image type you can look here [PHP, display image with Header()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2633908/php-display-image-with-header)

Comment: Thank you for the info! it's not displaying the raw text anymore but now i can't get the image to show, the whole browser page goes gray and there's a square in the middle. The filepath is correct i've checked many times.

Comment: @Luka you cant do this in a mixed media page, the page outputting the graphic should be separate, then you can call it like a regular image `<img src="page.php">`

Comment: Thank you so much, sorry for these silly questions i'm very new to PHP