# HTTP Image output gives blob data instead of image

Tags: php, mysql, http, yii2

My url looks like ..../image/view?id=6

Navigating to this url should give an image from my database.
But currently I'm getting a bunch of weird characters as a response.

When I output (see below) I'm seeing my image.

```
<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode( $image->Data ).'"/>
```

I'm using this piece of code to generate my HTTP response, but the response is just the blob data:

```
 header('Content-Type :'.$image->Extension);
 header('Content-Disposition: filename='.$image->Name.'.'.$image->Extension);
 header('Content-Length: ' . strlen($image->Data));
 $response->format = Response::FORMAT_RAW;
 $response->data = $image->Data;
```

Current output begins with:

```
����JFIF��>CREATOR: gd-jpeg v1.0 (using IJG JPEG v90), default quality ��C     $.' ",#(7),01444'9=82<.342��C     2!!22222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222���"��    ���}!1AQa"q2���#B��R��$3br�
```

Headers used:

```
   Accept-Ranges: bytes
   Cache-Control: private
   Content-Disposition: inline;        filename="FYdsl67l4PWJQ7QFFeo14Ena76gr0pEP.jpg"
   Content-Length: 320135
   Content-Type: image/jpeg
   Date: Mon, 28 Jan 2019 19:05:11 GMT
   Expires: 0
   Pragma: public
   Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
   X-Powered-By: PHP/5.6.24, ASP.NET
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: check your content type header. for more details check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2633908/php-display-image-with-header

Comment: Thx for the suggestion, but unfortunately, stil the same result.
My headers are now: http://prntscr.com/mcehqy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue has been fixed, seems that my file was in an incorrect encoding ...
File needed to be iso instead of utf-8

Answer (score 2):

If your image is base64 encoded when it goes in to the database, to display it, you either need to

1. Use `base64_decode($img)` and then display it. OR
2. Do this: echo `'<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,' . $image->Data . '"/>;`

What you seem to be doing is encoding it again.

Comment: Hi, the data isn't base64 encoded.
When I print the data to the browser it starts with:
����JFIF��>CREATOR: gd-jpeg v1.0 (using IJG JPEG v90), default quality ��C    $.' ",#(7),01444'9=82<.342��C  2!!22222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222���"�� ���}!1AQa"q2���#B��R��$3br� %&'()*456789:CDEFGHIJSTUVWXYZcdefghijstuvwxyz������������

Comment: Does it have the jpeg extension? Is it just this one image or all of them? What is the data type it's being stored as in the database?

Comment: It is all of them :(.
Installed a new database, and restored a backup of my previous database. Everything works fine. Except all my images and files in the database are having the same issue.
I've added a new image to my database, but still the same problem :(

I'm saving a binary string to the database, the database field has the type mediumblob

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use [`Response::sendContentAsFile()`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-web-response#sendContentAsFile()-detail) to send this file:

```
return Yii::$app->response->sendContentAsFile(
    $image->Data, 
    $image->Name . '.' . $image->Extension, 
    ['mimeType' => FileHelper::getMimeTypeByExtension($image->Name . '.' . $image->Extension)]
);
```

Note that `Conent-Type` header is not the same as file extension - refer to [`FileHelper::getMimeTypeByExtension()`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-helpers-basefilehelper#getMimeTypeByExtension()-detail).

Comment: Tested the code, the image is downloaded immediately to my pc.
Unfortunately, the image seems to be "damaged / corrupted or is too large".

While I'm able to display my image in an img tag by using base64 (but this isn't my preferred solution)

Comment: Are you sure you're not adding any excessive headers? Or output before file sending?

Comment: Hi, I've changed my code back to the original and added the headers to the question. The data is a binary string, which is in my database of type medium blob

Comment: You have two `Content-Type` headers. You need to figure out source of `Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8` header.

Comment: Changed my code to your sample, but added the parameter `'inline' => true`. The headers are more correct (question has been updated). But the image is still not visible on the link I'm using